# Proxmox switched IP now cant edit vm definitions

Tags: debian, proxmox

I have Proxmox VE 5.1-35.  Switched the IP address and now I cant seem to modify any the VM definitions:

I get an error about permissions:
[image: permission error]

I'm not much of a linux permissions debugger so I'm a bit stumped.  Heres the ls of that directory:
[image]

BTW, when the IP changed, I had to move everything from pve to pve1, not sure why that is, something about Proxmox

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can see that the directory is not writable by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the permissions when moving the files?  How did you accomplish the move?  (For something like this, you should supply the `-p` flag to `cp`, or the `-a` flag to `rsync` if using those tools.)

For the moment, `chmod u+w /etc/pve/nodes/pve1/qemu-server` should get you past this particular error, but if you changed other permission (intentionally or inadvertantly as part of the file move), you might run into more issues in the future.

Comment: i think i just used `cd /etc/pve/nodes/pve` then `mv qemu-server/* ../pve1/qemu-server`

Comment: i just ran `mount` and it says `/dev/fuse on /etc/pve type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)`.  I'm guessing thats the problem?